# How to create double query SQL?

Tags: sql

I would like to know how to receive one result, and, with that result, give it to a new query. This is what I have now:

```
   SELECT A.id_buc               AS BUC,
        A.id_promotor_ALTAIR     AS EJECUTIVO
     FROM cl_cliente       A
    WHERE A.id_buc=(SELECT B.id_contrato       AS CONTRATO,
                           B.id_buc            AS BUC,
                           B.fec_apertura      AS FECHA
                         FROM el_contrato       B
                        WHERE B.id_contrato IN (80121221158));
```

But this query throws me errors.

Comment: Please don't use tags which don't belong. Change `A.id_buc=` to `A.id_buc IN`.

Comment: You should add the error message you receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your query:

1. You should use `IN` rather than `=` in case there are two or more results from the inner query.
2. The inner query should only return a single column, the values of this column will server as a filter for the field to retrieve.

So, your query should look like this:

```
SELECT A.id_buc          AS BUC,
    A.id_promotor_ALTAIR AS EJECUTIVO
FROM cl_cliente A
WHERE A.id_buc IN (SELECT B.id_buc
                FROM el_contrato B
                WHERE B.id_contrato IN (80121221158));
```

But this query is very bad and will perform horribly. It will be better if you rewritten it in a single query by using `JOIN` and you can retrieve the data of both tables, as needed:

```
SELECT A.id_buc             AS BUC,
       A.id_promotor_ALTAIR AS EJECUTIVO,
       B.id_contrato        AS CONTRATO,
       B.id_buc             AS BUC,
       B.fec_apertura       AS FECHA
FROM cl_cliente A
     INNER JOIN el_contrato B ON A.id_buc = B.id_buc
WHERE B.id_contrato IN (80121221158);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're trying to create an inline view and join it to the other table?

```
SELECT A.id_buc AS BUC,
       A.id_promotor_ALTAIR AS EJECUTIVO, 
       B.*
FROM cl_cliente  A
INNER JOIN (SELECT B.id_contrato AS CONTRATO,
                   B.id_buc            AS BUC,
                   B.fec_apertura      AS FECHA
            FROM el_contrato       B
            WHERE B.id_contrato IN (80121221158)) B
    ON A.id_buc= B.ID_BUC
```

or maybe you just need to [learn how to use Joins...](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

```
SELECT A.id_buc              AS BUC,
       A.id_promotor_ALTAIR  AS EJECUTIVO,
       B.id_contrato         AS CONTRATO,
       B.id_buc              AS el_contrato_BUC,
       B.fec_apertura        AS FECHA
FROM cl_cliente A
INNER JOIN el_contrato B
  ON A.id_buc= B.ID_BUC  
WHERE B.id_contrato IN (80121221158)
```

Comment: Thanks, it just work with this: 

SELECT A.id_buc AS BUC, A.id_promotor_ALTAIR AS EJECUTIVO, B.id_contrato AS CONTRATO, B.id_buc AS el_contrato_BUC, B.fec_apertura AS FECHA FROM cl_cliente A INNER JOIN el_contrato B ON A.id_buc= B.ID_BUC WHERE B.id_contrato IN (80121221158)

Answer (score 0):

@xQbert

### Thanks, it just work with this:

---

> ---
>
> ```
> SELECT A.id_buc              AS BUC,
>         A.id_promotor_ALTAIR  AS EJECUTIVO,
>         B.id_contrato         AS CONTRATO,
>         B.id_buc              AS el_contrato_BUC,
>         B.fec_apertura        AS FECHA
>  FROM cl_cliente A
>  INNER JOIN el_contrato B
>    ON A.id_buc= B.ID_BUC
>
>  WHERE B.id_contrato IN (80121221158)
> ```
>
> ---

---